# unable to start Kafka sandbox HDP

Tags: apache-kafka, hortonworks-sandbox

I'am trying to run kafka from ambari UI. sandbox hdp. it does not start. i checked the log the error is :

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error creating broker listeners from 'sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:9092': Unable to parse sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:9092 to a broker $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this was resolved on the [Cloudera Community](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Producing-to-Kafka-HDP-Sandbox-2-6-4/td-p/189742). The key conclusion:

> It's worked for me after changing my listener ip from localhost to
> exact ip of virtualbox.